# Resources not found in Activity inheriting from nested library

Tags: android, android-resources, android-library

I've created two android library projects with shared code and resources for 3 apps. One of the libraries (I'll call it library A) has code and resources that are shared by all 3 apps and the other has code and resources that are shared only by two of the three (let's call it library B).

So I made library B depend on A. The problem I'm having is with the two apps that depend on library B. When starting the first Activity I get NoSuchFieldErrors or NullPointerExceptions when trying to access the elements in a xml layout defined in library B. It seems that it can't find the resources from the Super class in labrary B. I've created a small example that reproduces the problem.

**In library A:**

*AActivity.java:*

```
public class AActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        doStuff();
    }

    protected void doStuff() {
    }

}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testlib"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testliba.AActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**In library B:**

*BActivity.java:*

```
public class BActivity extends AActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_b);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.buttonText));
}

@Override
protected void doStuff() {
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setText("I'm a button");
}
}
```

*res/layout/activity_main_b.xml:*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="@string/buttonText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*AndroidManifest.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testlib"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testlibb.BActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**In app that depends on library B:**

*MainActivity.java:*

```
public class MainActivity extends BActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Contents specific for this Activity
    }
}
```

In the *gen* directory of the application I find three *R.java* generated:

- com.example.testapp
- com.example.testlibb
- com.example.testliba

and *id.button1* is present both in the *R.java* in *testapp* and *testlibb* and they have the same value in both. Still at runtime it's not found.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the AndroidManifest.xml in both library projects had the same default package

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testlib"
```

this caused problems when generating R.java. So to fix the issue I just had to change the default packages of the library projects so that they differed from eachother:

**In library A**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testliba"
```

**And in library B**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testlibb"
```

Answer (score 1):

In BActivity you are calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
After this following in AActivity is called

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
doStuff();
```

doStuff(); is overrided by BActivity

so Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); is called, but setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_b); still has not been called at this point

Comment: Good catch! Sorry, I was sloppy when making the example and assumed that the NullPointerException was a different symptom of the same issue I was having in my real project. The downvote was well deserved. When I fixed my example project according to your comments I was able to reproduce the same issue as in my real project. And shortly thereafter I found the solution (I've updated my question and will anwser it in case somebody runs into the same issue). Thanks for the help!